# javascript need help making variable global

Tags: javascript

In my code there is value I am trying to get called currentParameter.value, i need to make it global so that i can use it on another page. For some reason i cannot make currentParameter.value available globally. Whenever i try to do an alert on it, i get undefined. I dont know what is causing it, i thought anything could be made global. My code is below.

```
 function determineTemplate(customInt) {
     var templateArray = [];
     var hasDropdown = false;
      for(var i=0,maxI=customInt.length;i<maxI;i+=1) {
           var Interaction = customInt[i];

           for(var j=0,maxJ=Interaction.parameterSet.param.length;j<maxJ;j+=1) {
                  var currentParameter = Interaction.parameterSet.param[j];
                  if (currentParameter.name === 'INTERACTION-TYPE') {
                     if (currentParameter.value !== '_itemData') {

                        var intTemplate = {
                            'multipleChoice': {"type" : "04719d91", "data" : Interaction, "id" : Interaction.id},
                            'dragDrop': {"type" : "94ed89c0", "data" : Interaction, "id" : Interaction.id},
                            'dropdown': {"type" : "8a01a4d0", "data" : Interaction, "id" : Interaction.id},
                            'select': {"type" : "b1fb3531", "data" : Interaction, "id" : Interaction.id}
                        };

                        var currentTemp = intTemplate[currentParameter.value];                              

                        if (currentTemplate !== undefined) {
                            if (currentParameter.value === 'dropdown') {
                                if (!hasDropdown) {
                                    templateArray.push(currentTemplate);     
                                    hasDropdown = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                templateArray.push(currentTemp);     
                            }

                        }

                     }
                  }
           }
     };

     return templateArray; 
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "use it on another page"? It sounds, to me, like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what "global" means. It could be, instead, that you've explained yourself poorly. Any clarification?

Comment: short ans but not an elegant way , remove var before that variable.

Comment: You can't set a js variable on one page and use it on another page load without use of cookies or other means of transfer

Comment: I am trying to pass the value from here to into my requireJS file so that it can switch based on what that value is.

Answer (score 3):

To make it global you just need to change this line:

```
var currentParameter = Interaction.parameterSet.param[j];
```

to

```
window.currentParameter = Interaction.parameterSet.param[j];
```

However you will not be able to use in **another page** because `window` will change also.

Comment: How about the "so that i can use it on another page" part?

Comment: Indeed. I think you've answered the question in the title without much regard to the content in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.templateArray
```

instead of

```
var templateArray
```

This will declare the variable in the window scope, essentially global.

You can also declare the variable outside of the function scope. e.g:

```
var templateArray = [];
function determineTemplate(customInt) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but if you are trying to pass a variable from page to page, you can't do this with a global var.  Instead you'll need to pass the data through the url, or a cookie, or have the server persist it in some other way and sent it down to the page at load time.

I think global vars are evil, but if you do want to make `currentParameter.value` global here are two methods that comes to mind.

1) Make define `currentParameter` in the global scope, and use it in your function

2) you could add it to a global object, and call that object.

```
window.value= currentParameter.value
```